# C++ Failure comparing two std::chrono::time_points with same duration

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I´m trying to convert a `std::chrono::time_point` to a long variable and then back to a `std::chrono::time_point` class. The long variable will be used to send client/server messages on my architecture.

So I have the following test code (code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52af94ec1caaea45)):

```
int main ()
{
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    auto epoch = now.time_since_epoch();
    auto value = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(epoch);
    long duration = value.count();

    std::cout << "Duration=" << duration << std::endl;  

    std::chrono::milliseconds ms(duration);

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> dt(ms);

    auto epoch1 = dt.time_since_epoch();
    auto value1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(epoch1);
    long duration1 = value1.count();
    std::cout << "Duration1=" << duration1 << std::endl;  

    if (dt != now)
        std::cout << "Failure." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Success." << std::endl;
}
```

As from the output, I have:

```
Duration=1436221951916
Duration1=1436221951916
Failure.
```

Why are both durations the same but both times not the same (`Failure` on comparasion) ? What am I missing here ?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conversion from `std::chrono::time_point` to `long` rounds the time point to milliseconds.

See [this question on how properly serialize and deserialize `time_point`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22291506/persisting-stdchrono-time-point-instances).